# Calculating Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a table that i'm able to add a new row. If I manually type in the quantity and the price, the total is calculated using this javascript code.

```
function addRow() {
    addTableRow($('.table tbody'));
}

function removeRow() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    var tableSize = $('.table tbody tr').length;
    if(tableSize == '1'){
        alert('You must have one row');
        return false;
    }
    par.remove();
};

function calculateRow() {
    var par = $(this).parent().parent();
    var price = $(par).find('.price').val();
    var qty = $(par).find('.qty').val();
    var total = price*qty;
    $(par).find('.total').val(total.toFixed('2'));
}

$('.table tbody').on("click", ".removeRow", removeRow);
$('.table tbody').on("blur", ".qty", calculateRow);

function addTableRow(table) {
    $(table).append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td><input name='item_number[]' type='text' class='id form-control'></td>" +
        "<td><input name='item_name[]' type='text' class='name search form-control'></td>" +
        "<td><input name='item_price[]' type='text' class='price form-control price'></td>" +
        "<td><input name='item_qty[]' type='text' class='form-control qty'></td>" +
        "<td><input name='item_total[]' type='text' class='form-control total'></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center' style='vertical-align:middle;'><a href='#' class='text-success removeRow'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a></td>" +
        "</tr>");
    auto();
}
```

Now I've added Jquery UI AutoSuggest to my table and made it so I was able to fill the item number, item name, item quantity, and item price all by choosing a product. Using the javascript below:

```
    function auto() {
    var ac_config = {
        source: "/admin/items/fetch_items",
        select: function(event, ui){
            var item = ui.item;
            if(item) {
                $(".id").val(item.id);
                $(".price").val(item.price);
                $(".qty").val('1');
                var par = $(".qty").parent().parent();
                var price = $(par).find('.price').val();
                var qty = $(par).find('.qty').val();
                var total = price*qty;
                $(par).find('.total').val(total.toFixed('2'));
            }
        },
        minLength: 1,
    };
    $(".search").autocomplete(ac_config);
}
```

Now as you can see, I am needing to calculate the row total and fill it. As the code sits above, the initial row that is by default made by html is calculated correctly. But once I add a new row and try to autofill it and calculate the total, the first row changes along with the new row I just added.

How do I get the javascript to run on the row I just autofilled with the jQuery UI?

Comment: Your selectors like `$(".id")` will find all of same class in page. You need to define a way to target specific row. It could be by toggling a class on row, or always filling last row. What behavior are you looking for?

Comment: The toggling sounds easier and more logical, since we may be returning to a row to change a quantity or item all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a class like `selected` on the active row and add some highlighting css based on that class.

```
function addRow() {
    var $table = $('.table tbody');    
    addTableRow($table);
    $table.find('tr.selected').removeClass('selected').end().find('tr:last').addClass('selected');
}
```

Now within the autocomplete callback you can target the `selected` row with your selectors

```
var ac_config = {
    source: "/admin/items/fetch_items",
    select: function(event, ui){
        var item = ui.item;
        if(item) {
            var $row = $('tr.selected');
            $row.find(".id").val(item.id);
            $row.find(".price").val(item.price);

            /* ....... etc....*/
        }
    },
    minLength: 1,
};
```

Then somewhere in your initialization code add a click handler to toggle `selected` on row click:

```
$('.table tbody').on('click', 'tr',function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your question.

But is this usefull for you? 
With jquery you can each tr the and acumulate the values of each row

```
function total() {
   var total=0;
   $.each("table tr", function(key,row) {
      var tr=$(this);
      var qty=parseFloat(tr.find(".qty).val());
      var price=parseFloat(tr.find(".price).val());
      total+=qty*price;
  });
  return total;
}

$(".qty, .price").change(function(){
   var total=total();
   $(".total").html(total);
});
```

Comment: Not quite. When I type in the dollar amount of the item and then the quantity when I blur the quantity field, Javascript automatically multiplies these two together to find the total, it then fills that row's total field with the total. When I autofill using `jquery autosuggest` I need it to do the same thing. Right now it changes each row in the table to match that row I just created.

Comment: on autocomplette select methid call my function total() but before the return put the total of every row.